# Ordinary Differential Equation rewriting

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've a certainly stupid question. I have the following dynamical system of autonomous ODEs.

\begin{align}
\frac{dx_1}{dt}=f(x_1,x_2) \\
\frac{dx_2}{dt}=g(x_1,x_2) 
\end{align}

May I change the system to:

$$
\frac{dx_1}{dx_2} = \frac{f(x_1,x_2)}{g(x_1,x_2)}
$$

Thank you

Comment: yes, you can ..

Comment: Subject to $g(x) \neq 0$, of course :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be helpful if you are investigating the phase plane (portrait) of the given system of ODEs, since the dimension of your system is two. See the following link as an example, http://www.egr.msu.edu/~khalil/NonlinearSystems/Sample/Lect_3.pdf